# IE8 and the filepath in ajax .load

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following JS code works fine on IE9, FF, Opera

```
function LoadMyDiv(id){
var path = 'data/'+id+'.html';
$('#'+id).load(path);
}
```

I'm experiencing problems with IE 8, i.e. the content does not load. I've tried using `/data/'+id+'.html'` with no results.
When I move the file id+'.html' (e.g. test.html) to the root directory, the content is loaded properly, i.e. `$('#'+id).load(id+'.html')` works as expected. Hence, I suspect the problem is related to the path. Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
var path = './data/'+id+'.html';
```

Comment: I've tried this as well, but I still have the same issue. The funny/strange thing is that I have a similar function with path='data'+id (the rest is the same), and it works on IE8.